# GPG file encryption with nemo right click menu

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am using LinuxMint 18 with Cinnamon and trying to encrypt a file by using a custom command from right click menu.

I know `nemo-actions`.

1. I copied `sample.nemo-action` as `encrypt.nemo-action` and edited it.
2. I created a script named `encrypt.sh` and put my commands to it
3. I put both files to `~/.local/share/nemo/actions`
4. I used `nemo -q` (or `killall nemo`) then `nemo` to restart nemo in order to see my options.

Here are my files.

Content of `encrypt.nemo_action`

```
[Nemo Action]

Active=true
Name=Encrypt "%N"
Comment=Encrypt the file with a passphrase
Exec=<encrypt.sh "%F">
Icon-Name=folder
Selection=s
Extensions=any;
Quote=double
EscapeSpaces=true
```

Content of `encrypt.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --password | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output "$1.gpg" --symmetric "$1"
zenity --info --text="$1.gpg"
```

Now, the problem is, when I run this script in terminal, it does its job perfectly.
But when I run it from right click menu, zenity prompt shows up, I enter the passphrase, then info dialog shows up, but there is no output file.
Why? What am I doing wrong?

Note: Yes, I know `seahorse`.

Answer (score 1):

This action can work without file "sh".

```
Active=true
Name=Encrypt gpg
Comment=Encrypt the file with a passphrase
Exec=gpg "%F"
Icon-Name=gpg
Selection=s
Extensions=gpg;
Quote=double
EscapeSpaces=true
```

Or you can create script and open all files *.gpg with this script by default:

```
#!/bin/bash
fullpathname="$1"
path="${fullpathname%/*}"
cd $path
gpg --yes --use-embedded-filename "$fullpathname"
```